# QLPreviewController and iOS7: black screen

Tags: ios7, qlpreviewcontroller

I noticed that in iOS7, in a my app showing the preview of a document with the `QLPreviewController`, when I tap outside the page bounds (you note that better with a landscape pages document) the screen around the page become black (you can try it with the DocInteraction Apple sample). Is it a new iOS7 feature or a bug? How can I disable it?

Comment: What do you mean outside the page bounds?

Comment: I mean outside the bounds of the document's page shown. But I think this is a iOS7 feature.

Comment: you found any solution to this problem ?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug but a new iOS7 QLPreviewController appearance feature.